# gqlQuery returns object, want list of keys

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

*Is there a way to convert the GqlQuery object to an array of keys, or is there a way to force the query to return an array of keys?*   For example:

```
items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Items")
```

returns an object containing the keys:

```
<google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0x0415E210>
```

I need to compare it to an array of keys that look like:

```
[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Item', 100L, _app_id_namespace=u'items'),
 ..., datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Item', 105L, _app_id_namespace=u'fitems')]
```

Note:  I can get around the problem by querying for the stored objects, and then calling .key(), but this seems wasteful.

```
items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Items")
keyArray = []
for item in items:
  keyArray.append(item.key())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly - you can fetch the results by calling .fetch(count) on the GqlQuery object. This is the recommended way, in fact - iterating fetches results in batches, and so is less efficient.